# Typing for optional callable decorator in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-typings

I am writing typescript typings for some js library. I need to declare optionally callable decorator:

```
@model
class User {}

@model()
class User {}

@model('User')
class User {}
```

I tried to use `ClassDecorator` from `lib.es6.d.ts` but with no luck:

```
// works
export const model: ClassDecorator;

// error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression. Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'ClassDecorator | CallableModelDecorator' has no compatible call signatures
type CallableModelDecorator = (name?: string) => ClassDecorator;
export const model: ClassDecorator | CallableModelDecorator;
```

Of course I can make manual typing as workaround:

```
export function model<TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction): TFunction | void;
export function model(name?: string):
  <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void;
```

But how can I reuse existing `ClassDecorator` type in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using an union type, variables of these types only have the common members of both types, so in this case since only one of the types is callable, the union will not be callable

You are looking for an intersection type, that will have member of both of type types

```
export const model: ClassDecorator & CallableModelDecorator;
```

Comment: It works!  Thanks for the explanation. Docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html